# EOF on zeromq file transfer

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I am using the below Python code to transfer large files between a server and a client using zeromq.

**Implementation to send file, server**

```
    CHUNK_SIZE = 250000

    message = pair.recv() # message is the path to the file

    filename = open(message, 'rb')
    filesize = os.path.getsize(message)

    offsets = (int(ceil(filesize / CHUNK_SIZE)), 0)[filesize <= CHUNK_SIZE]

    for offset in range(offsets + 1):
        filename.seek(offset)

        chunksize = CHUNK_SIZE

        if offset == offsets:
            chunksize = filesize - (CHUNK_SIZE * (offset - 1)) # calculate the size of the last chunk

        data = filename.read(chunksize)

        pair.send(data)

    pair.send(b'')
```

**Implementation to receive file, client**

```
while True:
    data = pairs.recv()

    if data is not '':
        target.write(data)
    else:
        break
```

However, after transfer a large file using this implementation, for some reason an extra data is being added at end of the file:

**File server side**

```
$ stat file.zip 
  File: `file.zip'
  Size: 1503656416  Blocks: 2936840    IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

**Client side**

```
$ stat file.zip 
  File: `file.zip'
  Size: 1503906416  Blocks: 2937328    IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

The size and blocks are different between them.

That said, do you have any suggestions to calculate/send the end of file properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution. The `seek()` was not processing the chunks properly.

```
-filename.seek(offset)
+filename.seek(0, 1)
```

Thus, it will always get the offset 0 on current (last) position.

Now everything is working as expected :)